# Debug in Rider studio. Step into not working

Tags: .net, debugging, hotkeys, rider

The problem during debug when I try to press `Step into` hot key.
It is set to `F11` and `F7` by default. When I try to press F11 nothing happens. When I try to press `F7` it steps by code but when it must go into the method(`step into` it is the command special for this action) my debug mode turn off.
Rider turn off debug mode as I did it by button.

I tried to change to another hot key action `step into`. The result the same. When I try go inside to another method durring step debug and press `F7` or other key for `step into` my Rider stop debug mode.

I have a screen with `step into` on `F8`. The same result, my debug mode turn off when I try to go into the method during debug.

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: It's the same with me. When I click on step into the debug process is terminated. I'm using Rider arm64. Maybe it's a bug in Rider

Comment: What version of Rider do you use? It works fine for me using 2021.3

Comment: Have the same problem unfortunately with Rider 2021.3.3

Comment: My version is last on Rider from today JetBrains Rider 2021.3.3

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have an answer from JetBrains.

Need to uncheck external debbuging

`may I ask you to uncheck Enable external source debug setting (Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger)? Does it help you?`

Finally it works

Comment: Although this was helpful, it's still doesn't feel like a proper solution

Comment: Didn't work for me. But it doesnt work in visual studio either. Using a macbook air 2022

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a [bug in Rider [JetBrains Youtrack issue]](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-41630). I suggest that everyone who's affected votes for this issue to increase the urgency.

A partial solution seems to be: disable "Always do smart step into".

[image: Change settings]

Comment: Thanks but without result. I really confused with that.

Comment: This ticket is closed, but the issue persists

Comment: @dodbrian: they have disabled the feature and created [a new issue for adding that feature again](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-83690/Restore-Smart-Step-Into-in-async-code-functionality). I'm not impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Use JetBrains Rider as the default JIT debugger﻿

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S or alternatively select File | Settings from the main menu, then choose Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger on the left.
2. Click Set rider as default debugger.
3. When JetBrains Rider is set as the default JIT debugger and a process calls Debugger.

[Debugging in Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Starting_the_Debugger_Session.html)

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1 F11 key is used by Mission Control as a hotkey to show Desktop. So you can try this:

Go to the macOS System settings -> Functional keys -> Mission Control -> Show Desktop (F11) - uncheck this checkbox.